# Error: trying to diff 'value' Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

I have a component to add multiple values. When i tried to set its value using patch value, i get the error "error trying to diff  'oatMeal' Only arrays and iterables are allowed" how can i update its value?

Here is the code in plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/hfiJ3SQokGjOwsf9OviG?p=preview

This is the method i call to update the form field

```
updateForm() {
      this.formGroup.patchValue({venueAmenities: 'oatmeal'});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you will need to pass an array to your `ngFor`. In your case, `venueAmenities` should be an array, and hence your patched value should be an array too.

This is how you should do it.

```
updateForm() {
      this.formGroup.patchValue({venueAmenities: ['oatmeal']});
}
```

Working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HFixvRghZPpdtnD0HlHq?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was have `[(ngModel)]="MyModell"`, I just write (`ngModel)="MyModell"` and work. In HTML code of course.